# How to extract table from websitewhen the numbers do not show in the html?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying extract the tables in the website below for all industries and periods. When I download the html however, the numbers displayed in the website are not found anywhere. How can I retrieve the entries of the table?

https://csimarket.com/Industry/industry_Efficiency.php?ind=102

My code below extracts the html. Upon inspection, the numbers in the table do not appear anywhere, so I can't extract them. The question is then where are they? And how can they be accessed and extracted?

Please, note that I am new to requests and beautiful soup! 
Many thanks!

```
import requests

my_target='https://csimarket.com/Industry/industry_Efficiency.php?ind=102'

r  = requests.get(my_target)
data = r.text
```

Comment: Requests doesn't load data generated by Javascript, so it wouldn't show up in beautifulsoup

Comment: @cricket_007, would there be any workaround?

Comment: Selenium Webdriver is the more commonly used alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `requests` but you, need to use `r.content` instead of `r.text`:

```
import requests

my_target='https://csimarket.com/Industry/industry_Efficiency.php?ind=102'

r  = requests.get(my_target)
data = r.content
```

You may also use [`BeautifulSoup` module](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the `html`, like this:

```
import requests
#load beautifullsoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
my_target='https://csimarket.com/Industry/industry_Efficiency.php?ind=102'
r  = requests.get(my_target)
#get raw html
data = r.content
#soup the content
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
#find table element
table_element = soup.find('table',{"class":"osnovna_tablica_bez_gifa"})
#print text version of table element
print table_element.text
```

Which give you:

```
Chemicals - Plastics & Rubber Industry
3 Q
2 Q
1 Q
4 Q
3 Q


 

2018
2018
2018
2017
2017


Revenue/Employee (TTM) $
428,075
327,852
323,322
338,175
325,069


Sales/Employee Ranking
# 22
# 78
# 79
# 68
# 74


Net Income/Employee (TTM) $
37,510
18,571
20,953
27,151
18,810


Net Income/Employee 
                  Ranking 
# 16
# 72
# 69
# 58
# 64


Receivable Turnover Ratio (TTM)
7.53
5.17
5.07
5.17
5.11


Receivable Turnover Ranking 
# 31
# 88
# 90
# 87
# 89


Inventory Turnover Ratio (TTM) Sales
8.1
5.56
5.65
6.13
6.45


Inventory Turnover (Sales)
                  Ranking 
# 31
# 90
# 90
# 86
# 85


Inventory Turnover Ratio (TTM) COS
5.77
3.83
3.81
4.16
4.37


Inventory Turnover (COS)
                  Ranking 
# 24
# 79
# 81
# 75
# 77


Asset Turnover Ratio (TTM)
0.92
0.47
0.52
0.6
0.69


Asset Turnover Ranking 

# 31
# 72
# 68
# 63
# 49
```

Comment: You can also find all 'tr' or 'td' elements directly using find_all('tr') or find_all('td'), or if you need only a specific one using class or id with the same syntax used to find table_element

Answer (score 0):

You can use the urllib package and then extract your numbers using regular expressions. Do:

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

url = "https://csimarket.com/Industry/industry_Efficiency.php?ind=102"
response = http.request('GET', url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data)

spans = soup.find_all("span")

for span in spans:

  print(span)
```

This gives:

```
<span class="">428,075</span>
<span class="">327,852</span>
<span class="">323,322</span>
...
<span class="siva3">31</span>
<span class="siva3"># 5</span>
<span class="siva3"># 31</span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the numbers are now found! Is there a preferred way to then extract them you are thinking of?

Comment: Your data is stored in the span elements, therefore you could for example use BeautifulSoup to extract there and then process them. Or pick <td> or <tr> or whatever suits your future analysis best.

Answer (score 0):

Much tidier would be to use pandas `read_html`

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html('https://csimarket.com/Industry/industry_Efficiency.php?ind=102')
print(tables[6].fillna(''))
```